# Invalid read even though object exists

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am trying to implement a self-balancing binary search tree. When I try to get the height of the right branch, it works until I reach this point. Then I get a segmentation fault error and valgrind says there was an invalid read of size 8. The odd thing is when I look at the tree when this error occurs, the right branch isn't null. Is there some check that I am forgetting to do that is causing this error?

Lines where error is thrown:

```
int rightChildHeight = 0;
if (n->right != NULL)
    rightChildHeight = n->right->getHeight();
```

getHeight():

```
int Node::getHeight()
{
// No kids => 2
if (!left && !right)
    return 1;
// 1 kid => height of kid +1
else if (!left && right)
    return right->getHeight() + 1;
else if (left && !right)
    return left->getHeight() + 1;
// 2 kids => height of taller kid +1
else
    return max(left->getHeight(), right->getHeight()) + 1;
}
```

Tree when the error occurs:

[image: Tree when the error occurs.]

Comment: *"the right branch isn't null"* - Doesn't mean it holds a valid address either. You have bug somewhere in the tree's initialization/rotation/insertion/deletion. We can't find it for you psychically.

Comment: Most likely, `right` is a "dangling pointer" (i.e. it is non-null but it is not pointing at a valid object -- this typically happens if the object it was pointing at was deleted, but the pointer was not modified, so it remains pointing at the memory location where the object previously existed.  Dereferencing a dangling pointer is an error and invokes undefined behavior)

Comment: Pointer n is not pointing to a valid address.

Comment: @TungLeThanh But if I point to n->left I get no error. Does that mean n->right isn't pointing to a valid address?

Comment: @BlakeMorgan: if your program working memory space is trully at 0x5555555xxxxx, n is valid, sorry for that. I see Valgrin ou debug program fills out unused/uninitialized memory with 0x55 sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are initiating the `left` and `right` pointers as `nullptr`. Probably you are not and it's getting random data from that memory location, making the pointer exist but it's not pointing to an object with a `right` property. Also if you delete any node before that show us the delete method and the insert method. There might be a problem in one of those functions.

Also you should try to be consistent with your code, first you check for nullability like this `if (n->right != NULL)` and after like this `if (!left && !right)` to be honest I prefer the second way, it's cleaner.